# HTML Form input form - client-side size limit and auto-adding dashes

Tags: javascript, maskedinput

How do i write my HTML input forms like this:
Example:
Instead of typing:

```
012345678910
```

...when typing in the forms it will do this

```
01-234567891-0
```

...like include dashes and limit to only 12 digits integer?

Comment: This is a Javascript question

Answer (score 0):

You'll need javascript do to that.

Look at [JQuery.InputMask](http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/) for a start.